# Concerns about returning all elements from a `StorageDoubleMap`

Tags: storage, iteration

I defined a storage item as `StorageDoubleMap`, and I need to provide a method that returns the **list of elements with the first key (k1)**. This getter method has to be provided by the pallet. I found a [method](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageDoubleMap.html#method.iter_prefix) in frame that provides what I need.

However, I'm aware that iterating over an unbounded storage item might lead to undesired behavior. Is there any recommendation or best practice to accomplish this?

EDIT: The use case is to provide a way to iterate over the collection in a safe manner. Let's imagine this collection of items is consulted by another pallet.

Comment: You'd better improving your service structure. Iterating over a map haphazardly is unwise IMO.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier I see, do you know if there is any common pattern? It seems to be an issue that people commonly face

Comment: What's the use case? maybe with the idea of what you need we can see a better solution than iterate the StorageDoubleMap inside the runtime

Comment: @AlexBean use case added in the edit section

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions called `iter_prefix` and `iter_prefix_from` in the `StorageDoubleMap` that can be used for this.
The `iter_prefix_from` takes a previous key and resume iteration at that spot. So each time after iterating x keys, the last key is stored and in the next block the iteration can be resumed.

The tricky part it that iterating through a map should only be done while the map is not being modified. So possibly you need to add some locking mechanism or somehow differently ensure that the map will not have insert/deletes while it is being iterated.
AFAIK it still "works", but i think its not tested for and generally bad practice.